# Delete account from Firebase by user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security

I would need to set up rules for the Firebase database so that a user is able to delete their own account. This is what the function looks like in the swift

```
 func deleteAccount() {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            return
        }
       
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document(user.uid).delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
          
            user.delete { error in
                if let error = error {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).configureInitialViewController()
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is what the rules look like

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
        ".delete": "auth != null && auth.uid == resource.data.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when I click on the delete account button it throws me an error : "Missing or insufficient permissions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security rules you're showing apply to the Realtime Database, while the code you're showing is accessing Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the security rules for one don't apply to the other.

To fix the error, you will have to set the [rules for the Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).